# Update mySql table according to different conditions

Tags: mysql, vba

I got this code from this site and now I need to add some change.

I know I acted fool here.

I searched many and got stuck in here. I wanted to add 1 to the sql table @subject column where @name is the row. @subject and @name are changing. That is why parameters used.

```
Dim sql As String = "UPDATE attendance.student SET @subject = @subject +1 WHERE S_name = @name;” 
Dim conn As MysqlConnection 
Try conn = New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
  Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
  cmd.Parameters.Add(“@subject”, MySqlDbType.VarString, 20).Value = TextBox4.Text
  cmd.Parameters.Add(“@name”, MySqlDbType.VarString, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: _@subkect can't be used in that way only like you use _@name. Subject column name has to be concatinated

Comment: @nbk Can you show me the way of getting the required results? Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 0):

You must do this, to get it running
But it must be clear this is **vulnurable to sql injection**

So you **must check** TextBox4.Text for valid content.

```
Dim sql As String = "UPDATE attendance.student SET `" & TextBox4.Text & "` = `" & TextBox4.Text & "` +1 WHERE S_name = @name;” 
Dim conn As MysqlConnection 
Try conn = New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
  Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(sql, conn)
  cmd.Parameters.Add(“@name”, MySqlDbType.VarString, 50).Value = TextBox1.Text
```

Comment: Sorry. It is not working. I typed it and check everything again and again. Still nothing happening. Can I get any more method. I don’t care it’s like mine either. You can put any code you want. Because now I am fedup of trying this

Comment: no, enable general logging on the mysql server and see what query you get, i think that your update query fails because S_name  is no primary key, but check that in mysql workbench, with the actual query.

Comment: Now I retry it by putting primary key as S_Name, but no update in it. I don’t know what to do. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: didi you check themysql server and the log of it, i can't tell you what is wrong in my server it works just fine with sname as primary key., do as i saubd before enable the general log copy the new query that should appear after running your code and test it in workbench.

Comment: I checked @nbk. Thank you so much. I corrected it. Thank you again.